# Creating an animation in the render tab

Tags: houdini

I am new to Houdini but I was able to make a nice scientific visualization in the "Render View " window. I would like to have my model spin/rotate. I found a way to do that in "Scene View" but is there a way to do his in "Render View"

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already using geometry operators.

Within geo, you may add "transform node" at the end of your nodes, then use something like "$F * 10" in ry option.